# Grails 3 exclude class

Tags: gradle, grails

I am developing a grails plugin and I would like to exclude a class at build time. Let's say I have a service under grails-app/services/MyService.groovy. I would like to build 2 versions of this plugin, one which contains MyService, one which doesn't. Is there a way to achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your plugin descriptor you can define `pluginExcludes` to express items that you want excluded from the plugin.  For example:

```
def pluginExcludes = [
    '**/com/demo/**'
]
```

You can also exclude contents from the jar file:

```
// build.gradle
jar {
    exclude "com/demo/**"
}
```

More info available at https://docs.grails.org/3.3.x/guide/plugins.html.

Comment: I have answered the question as asked, but what you are asking how to do really isn't a good idea.  Rather than have 2 versions of the plugin, one with the service and one without, a better idea might be to have a plugin that provides the service, let that plugin depend on the main plugin which does not contain the service.  If you want the service, install the former, if you don't, install the latter.